# how to show the hdfs root directory in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I worked with hadoop 2.8.1, according to some reference( a lot of book and other online forum) that tell me where I could use 'hadoop fs -ls / ' to find the hdfs file system root. but while I type that command, the terminal show the local directory but not hdfs root.

what's wrong with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, that's the correct command (though `hdfs dfs -ls /`) is a more modern equivalent.  Are you sure it's not showing you the right thing?

Comment: @puhlen I am pretty sure!  it's very same when I enter 'hdfs dfs -ls' and 'ls -ls'

Comment: then maybe you have something wrong with your hadoop install, causing it to connect to your local file system instead of your cluster .

Comment: What do you see when you execute `hadoop version`?

Comment: @MateuszGrabowski below is content while execute hadoop version:Hadoop 2.8.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 20fe5304904fc2f5a18053c389e43cd26f7a70fe
Compiled by vinodkv on 2017-06-02T06:14Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 60125541c2b3e266cbf3becc5bda666
This command was run using /Users/suoyong/hadoop-2.8.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.1.jar

Comment: I run hadoop on my Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can execute `hadoop version` command and it returns correct information, it means that Hadoop was installed good.

I think there might be a problem with HDFS configuration. Try this:

1. Locate `core-site.xml` file in your local file system. It should be located in `/etc/hadoop/conf` directory.
2. Open `core-site.xml` file and locate this property:

   ```
   <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://<name-of-your-host>:8020</value>
        <final>true</final>
   </property>
   ```
3. I suppose `name` parameter is wrong. You have to identify the address on which HDFS is running and update it in `core-site.xml`.

Comment: exactly! thank you so much.but addition issue is why I run 'hadoop fs -ls /' without config core-site.xml which will show me local directory file?